# Filtering feed by tags is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, feed

The following feed is supposed to give me all MSO posts tagged `[status-completed]` but **not** tagged `[retag-request]`:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/status-completed+-retag-request

Instead, it is only giving me posts tagged with **both** tags.

Based on my Google Reader history, it looks like this was broken on May 27.

Comment: The same page search works but as you report the feed doesn't (feed link at the bottm): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed+-retag-request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build - it was inappropriately stripping the negative on any tags provided.